# how to create a date that doesn't change on a Django webpage

Tags: django

I created a webpage in Django that shows a list of items from a database. I would like to create a feature where when a user first generates that page, the current date (not time) appears on the page. The hard part is that when the user shares a link to that page on social media or wherever, the original date should remain unchanged. In other words, it should not change each time a subsequent user views the page through the link shared by the first user. The date is only created once when the first user generates the page.

The purpose is to show subsequent viewers of that page all the relevant database items as of the date the first user accessed them. But then I will also provide information about the number of additional relevant entries that have been made to the database since the date the first user accessed them. Subsequent users would then have the option of going to a new page that shows all database items as of today. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track when the user generated a page using a model. One of the field for that model should be 'created' as shown below(of course the name can be anything). Then override the save method of that model to update the created field only at initial creation. (This is a standard technique used in django to track item creation date)

```
from datetime import date

class Yourmodel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''
        if not self.id:
            self.created = date.today()
        return super(Yourmodel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is helpful!

Comment: @henrich, Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: i'm happy to do so, but don't see how I mark it as accepted. Please advise and I'm happy to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @henrich, Please visit this link. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Basically click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.